# Firebase ML Barcode exceptions - BarcodeDetectorCreator is declared final

Tags: android, firebase-mlkit

I'm not sure why do I get the following errors with the following code:

```
override fun analyze(
    imageProxy: ImageProxy,
) {
    Timber.d("Inside analyze")
    val currentTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
    if (currentTimestamp - lastAnalyzedTimestamp >= TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1)) {
        imageProxy.image?.let { imageToAnalyze ->
            val image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromMediaImage(
                imageToAnalyze,
                imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees
            )
            detector.detectInImage(image)
                .addOnSuccessListener { barcodes ->
                    if (barcodes.isNotEmpty()) {
                        Timber.d("Scanned: $barcodes")
                        onBarcodesDetected(barcodes)
                    } else {
                        Timber.d("No barcode scanned")
                    }
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                    Timber.d("BarcodeAnalyser: Something went wrong with exception: $exception")
                }
                .addOnCompleteListener {
                    imageProxy.close()
                }
        }
        lastAnalyzedTimestamp = currentTimestamp
    } else {
        imageProxy.close()
    }
}
```

Exception 1:

> java.lang.VerifyError: Superclass
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.barcode.internal.zzj of
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.barcode.BarcodeDetectorCreator is
> declared final (declaration of
> 'com.google.firebase.ml.vision.barcode.BarcodeDetectorCreator' appears
> in
> /data/app/~~xtNwRdP-8INX_Et8TKobrw==/com.ecoscanner.android-N16rSJ0NNkb2A00mYWrcRw==/base.apk!classes22.dex)
> at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)

Exception 2:

> ```
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>                                                                                                   at
> ```
>
> com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkArgument(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:1)
> at
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.common.FirebaseVisionImageMetadata$Builder.setRotation(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision@@24.0.3:8)
> at
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.common.FirebaseVisionImage.fromMediaImage(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision@@24.0.3:24)
> at
> com.ecoscanner.android.features.scanner.BarcodeAnalyser.analyze(ScannerScreen.kt:142)
> at
> androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis.lambda$setAnalyzer$2(ImageAnalysis.java:481)
> at
> androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.analyze(Unknown
> Source:2)
> at androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysisAbstractAnalyzer

p.s. libs versions:

```
androidxCameraBom = "1.2.3"
firebaseBom = "32.1.1"
firebaseMLVision = "24.0.3"
firebaseMLVisionBarcodeModel = "16.0.1"
gmsPlugin = "4.3.15"
```

Comment: wow, this is insane, I instead switched to non firebase version of barcode scanner and it works...